# ExecuteScalar() method and cursor in oracle stored procedure throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I want  to fetch the date of birth of the user on the basis of its id( userid) from the oracle database through the oracle stored procedure by using  ExecuteScalar() method . below is  the code for this  -

**In .net data Access Layer**

```
public DateTime GetuserDOB (int userid)
{
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("PKG_INFORMATION.SP_ GetuserDOB "))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("userid ", OracleDbType.Int32, userid, ParameterDirection.Input);
        command.Parameters.Add("UserDOBCursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
        return orcleHelper.GetDateValue(command);
    }
}
```

**In database helper class**

```
public  DateTime GetDateValue(OracleCommand command)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_ConnectString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.Connection = conn;
        object objDate = null;
        DateTime  returneddate  = new DateTime();
        objDate = command.ExecuteScalar();
        returneddate  = (objDate == DBNull.Value) ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime) objDate;

        return returneddate;
   }
}
```

**Stored Procedure in oracle database**

```
PROCEDURE SP_ GetuserDOB
(
  userid IN int,
  UserDOBCursor  OUT Page

)
AS
BEGIN
 OPEN UserDOBCursor  FOR 
   SELECT  USER_BIRTH_TIME  FROM  USERS WHERE USER_ID = userid;   
  EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20040,'Unable to retrieve the date of  birth');
 END SP_ GetuserDOB;
```

It is throwing below error

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Could somebody help me on that?

Thanks a lot.

NOTE - IF i am not using cursor i am getting the error

"
Invalid parameter binding 
Parameter name: userid"
"

Comment: Dates aren't cursors. You don't need a cursor if all you want to do is return a single date anyway.

Comment: Rewrite your procedure to become a function returning a date.

Comment: Sorry Guys , it isPage in place of Date